# Store and manage files between two applications?

Tags: iphone

It is possible to store some application files and share it with another application?

Can application A remove files created in such shared space by application B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.  There are a few things you can consider.

1. All apps can read/write/share photos via the user's photos library.
2. Some apps have been known to share data via the address book.  That is, they put data in a special address card which can be read by multiple apps.
3. If the apps have matching App ID bundle seeds, they can access the same keychain entries.  I'm not sure how much data can be stored in the keychain, but it is possible to share data this way.
4. Apps can pass data to each other via a launch URL.  That is, one app can ask iOS to open a URL that launches the next app, and that URL can have parameters that pass data.

Answer (score 0):

No, each application has its own sandbox. Only way to communicate is to use custom URLs to call the other application or have a 'middle man' (eg a computer).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to RupertP's answer, the only real work-around is to use a globally-accessible server. A lot of iOS devs use MobileMe's iDisk (not free) or DropBox (free for a limited account).